# User Input with Range Sliders to generate D3js Donut Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graphing

Im trying to create a d3js donut graph based on a number of input range sliders.

Currently I have something thrown together from other peoples work - [this](http://codepen.io/peterbinks/pen/dMMgKP):

```
var width = 500,
  height = width,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  slices = 5,
  range  = d3.range(slices),
  color  = d3.scale.category10();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) { return d; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .innerRadius(radius/1.6);

// Set up the <svg>, then for each slice create a <g> and <path>.
var paths = d3.select("svg")
    .attr({ width: width, height: height })
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .selectAll(".arc")
    .data(range)
    .enter()
      .append("g")
        .attr({ class : "arc", style: "stroke: #fff;" })
      .append("path")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

// Create as many input elements as there are slices.
var inputs = d3.select("form")
  .selectAll(".field")
  .data(range)
  .enter()
    .append("div")
      .attr("class", "field")
    .append("label")
      .style("background", function (d) { return '#FFFFFF'; })
    .append("input")
    .attr({
      type  : "range",
      min   : 0,
      max   : 4000,
      value : 1,
      step  : 1,
      value : 500,
      class : "range",
      id    : function(d, i) { return "v" + i; },
      oninput : "update()"
    });

// update() sets the <path>s to the pie slices that correspond
// to the slider values. It is called when the page loads and
// every time a slider is moved.

function getTotal () {
    var total = 0;    
    d3.selectAll('.range').each(function () {
        total = total + parseInt(this.value);
    });
    return total;
}

function showValues () {
    d3.selectAll('.range').each(function () {
        var perct = this.value + '%';
        d3.select(this.parentNode.nextSibling).html(perct);
    });
}

function update () {
  var data = range.map(
    function(i) { return document.getElementById("v" + i).value }
  );

  paths.data(pie(data)).attr("d", arc);
}

update();
```

I need to sent the value for and range for each input, ideal in the html markup, as well as display the value and label for each input.

I've been seeing a lot of different types of d3js graphs that come close to this, but I haven't seen on that really gets all these elements together.

This comes kinda close [from this](http://codepen.io/peterbinks/pen/vGmdJe), but I also need the segments to update with the range slider.
Thanks in advance

This is a big problem, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would you mind to post your code at blockbuilder.org? that makes it easier to debug and collaborate toward a working solution..

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Your current work seems to function well, you just want to add labels that show the value on each slice?